# Thread-safe Logger object using the singleton pattern

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, thread-safety, singleton

I should implement a logger for an application and I should use the singleton pattern. Moreover, since this application is multithreaded, this logger should be thread-safe. I would like to point out that I have to use **C++03**.

I've seen [this implementation of singleton pattern](http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Singleton_pattern#Implementation) in C++/QT using a `QMutex` static object in order to guarantee that only one thread allocates the unique instance of the singleton object.

Why does everybody return a singleton as a pointer? I would return it as a reference, so I should not worry about explicitly free the memory used by the singleton object. I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/271104) and [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8699568/364056) and I wrote the following implementation.

```
// ==========
// Logger.h

#include <QMutex>
#include <QString>

class Logger
{
public:
    static Logger& instance();

    void configure(const QString& folder);

private:
    Logger();
    Logger(const Logger&);
    Logger& operator=(const Logger&);

private:
    mutable QMutex _mutex;
    QString _folder;
};


// ==========
// Logger.cpp

Logger::Logger() : _mutex() { ; }

Logger& Logger::instance()
{
    static QMutex mutex;

    mutex.lock();
    static Logger instance;
    mutex.unlock();

    return instance;
}

void Logger::configure(const QString& folder)
{
    _mutex.lock();
    _folder = folder;
    _mutex.unlock();
}
```

I have some questions...

1. Is the function `instance()` thread-safe when the unique instance is created?
2. At the time of the destruction of the object, will the singleton object destroyed in thread-safe manner?

Comment: A better method would be to have the Logger implement a void Log(const QString&) slot. This allows all objects to emit a Log signal to send to the log and will work across threads.

Comment: @Merlin069: Signals and slots provide a better way to accomplish my goal, but they require an event loop to be running and I noticed that unfortunately some opencv functions (like the `cvShowImage` function) crash when an event loop is running.

Comment: You could pack your instance of the `Logger` class into a `QSharedPointer` which is thread-save for access from different threads. See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsharedpointer.html#thread-safety

Comment: For a different, yet interesting, implementation of thread-safety see [QsLog](https://bitbucket.org/razvanpetru/qt-components/wiki/QsLog).

Comment: @thomas_b: from the linked documentation: "It should be noted that, while the pointer value can be accessed in this manner, QSharedPointer and QWeakPointer provide no guarantee about the object being pointed to."